# How do I add text to the bottom of my field text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hello I am trying to get text to the bottom instead of the top of my field text

[image]

Green is where I want the text to go but the red is where it is currently going

Here is my code:

```
#Tk Stuff

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1200x1200")
window.title("MSU RPG")
field = tk.Text(window, height = 15,width = 45,font=("Arial", 16))
field.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=11)

#Tk field text

field_text = ""
def atf(sth):
    global field_text
    field_text = field_text+str(sth)
    field.delete("1.0", "end")
    field.insert("1.0", field_text)

def clear():
    global field_text
    field_text= ""
    field.delete("1.0", "end")
```

I have tried a few different things from youtube videos, I have tried adding a scrollbar but scrollbars seem kinda complicated so I think this is the better way of doing it

Comment: Add enough newlines at the beginning.

Comment: Depending on how you want to process the text later, you can also use 2 text widgets. With the `bd` argument you can even set the border to 0, so it looks like one widget.

Comment: To clarify I also want the text to go upwards for example:


Top


Hi (message)
Bottom

now if u want to say another message it would be like 

top 

Hi (message)
Cheese (message)
bottom

so I want the old messages to be sent upwards

Comment: Keep adding text (or newlines) until it reaches the end of the widget. With `field.see('end')` you automatically display the last line which looks like your text moves up. You can still scroll to see the older messages.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding to the start of a textbox insrt at the end use

```
field.insert (END, field text)
```

You are inserting the text at first place try inserting at the end

```
#Tk Stuff

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1200x1200")
window.title("MSU RPG")
field = tk.Text(window, height = 15,width = 45,font=("Arial", 16))
field.grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=11)

#Tk field text

field_text = ""
def atf(sth):
    global field_text
    field_text = field_text+str(sth)
    field.delete("1.0", "end")
    field.insert (END, field text)

def clear():
    global field_text
    field_text= ""
    field.delete("1.0", "end")
```

I hope it would solve your problems.

Comment: When there is nothing in the text widget, inserting at END is the same as "1.0".

Comment: then two functionas are needed one  for inserting at the bottom and other to insert from the start one after another . The position second insertion will be defined by the length of first inserted number and so on.